# Add data to sqlite database when database is created

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to the `sqlite` database and in my project, I need to add data just after create the database. I tried in this way and here is my code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    MySqlHelper helper = new MySqlHelper(this); 
    v.setText(helper.getBird(2));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I created another class to open sqlite database.

public class MySqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BirdDB";
    private static final String TABLE_BIRDS = "birds";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME};

public MySqlHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE birds ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "name TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    db.close();

    SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    dbase.insert(TABLE_BIRDS, null, addBirdData("Sri Lanka Jungle Flowl"));
    dbase.insert(TABLE_BIRDS, null, addBirdData("Red Faced Mal Koha"));
    dbase.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS birds");
    this.onCreate(db);
}


public ContentValues addBirdData(String birdName){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, birdName);
    return values;
}
```

public String getBird(int id){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_BIRDS, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " id = ?", // c. selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();


    String name = cursor.getString(1);
    db.close();

    return name;
}
```

It gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: (conn# 0) already closed` exception

Help me to avoid from this and achieve to insert data just after database creation.

Comment: On an unrelated note - if you intend to use your database with a `Cursor` for populating a `ListView` (or other classes which extend `AdapterView`), change the name of your id column to be `_id`. Note the underscore prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database helper `onCreate()` you cannot call `getWritableDatabase()`. Instead, perform the inserts on the `db` passed in as a parameter to the method. Do not call `close()` on it.

After modifying the database helper `onCreate()`, uninstall your app so the old database file is removed and the code in `onCreate()` gets run.

Answer (score 1):

You *must not* close the database from inside the `onCreate` callback; the caller still has an active transaction.

Just use the `db` parameter for all database operations.